# Reverse for 'blogpost' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

Reverse for 'blogpost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P[0-9]+)\Z']

I face this problem in every project. So please any devloper solve this problem

**my urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='Blog_home'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.blogpost, name='blogpost'),
]
```

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'post':post}
    return render(request, 'blog/bloghome.html', context)

def blogpost(request, pk):
    blog_post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'blog_post':blog_post}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost.html', context)
```

**my models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Template: bloghome.html**

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block title %} Blog {% endblock title %}

{% block blogactive %} active {% endblock blogactive %}

{% block style %}
    .overlay-image{
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
{% endblock style %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  {% for post in post %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 py-4">
        <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
          <!-- <div class="col-auto m-auto img-fluid">
            <img src="#">
          </div> -->
          <div class="col p-4 blog d-flex flex-column position-static">
            <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">Code</strong>
            <h3 class="mb-0">{{post.title}}</h3>
            <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{post.date_and_time}}</div>
            <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{post.content | truncatechars:150}}</p>
            <div class="my-2">
              <a href="{% url 'blogpost' blog_post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

**Template: blogpost.html**

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block title %} Blog {% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

**Error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Reverse for 'blogpost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\Z']
```

Error at Template: bloghome.html

```
<a href="{% url 'blogpost' blog_post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue reading</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Post


def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blog/bloghome.html', context)


def blogpost(request, pk):
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    context = {'blog_post': blog_post}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost.html', context)
```

- bloghome.html

```py
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block title %} Blog {% endblock title %}

{% block blogactive %} active {% endblock blogactive %}

{% block style %}
    .overlay-image{
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
{% endblock style %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 py-4">
        <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
          <!-- <div class="col-auto m-auto img-fluid">
            <img src="#">
          </div> -->
          <div class="col p-4 blog d-flex flex-column position-static">
            <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">Code</strong>
            <h3 class="mb-0">{{post.title}}</h3>
            <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{post.date_and_time}}</div>
            <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{post.content | truncatechars:150}}</p>
            <div class="my-2">
              <a href="{% url 'blogpost' post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bloghome.html template expects to have a variable named `blog_post`:

```
{% url 'blogpost' blog_post.id %}
```

But you are not passing any such variable into the template:

```
def index(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'post':post}
    return render(request, 'blog/bloghome.html', context)
```

You are passing a variable named `post`, not `blog_post`.

Answer (score 0):

In bloghome.html,

instead of, `<a href="{% url 'blogpost' blog_post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue reading</a>`

try, `<a href="{% url 'blogpost' post.post_id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue reading</a>`

and in blogpost.html,

instead of,             `<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>`

try,      `<h2>{{blog_post.title}}</h2>`